# how to get label from custom tablayout?

Tags: android

I am creating tabs with icons and text using ,

```
 private void setupTab() {

        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : tabvalues.entrySet()) {
            try {
                TextView tabView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(baseActivity).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
                tabView.setText(entry.getKey());
                tabView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
                tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, entry.getValue(), 0, 0);

               tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tabView);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

now I wnt to get the text of the tab,

tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getText().toString();

It is returning null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
((TextView)tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getCustomView()).getText().toString();
```